# do i host react app, node js and mongo db separatly to host my whole website for free?

Tags: mongodb, cpanel, web-hosting, mern

I have made mern stack website that uses react, node, mongo and API. I want to ask if I want to host my website for free to test its functionalities, should I need to host it separately or can I host it on cpannel ?

and can you recommend me youtube video or document to host mern app to cpannel for free

Answer (score 0):

You can host your backend with Heroku:
A video for it as you asked (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27GoRa4d15c)

There are two ways I prefer to host the frontend:

1. With netlify
2. Github pages
   Using netlify is easy however using it free will limit hours it can be active monthly or something. But GitHub pages is also free.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-deploy-react-application-on-github-pages/

This is a site for deploying on github pages.
And here is a video on deploying with netlify (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KGLOJHqNMg)

Before you judge me on the videos I have not watched them fully so I do not know how good they explain it but you can search on youtube and find plenty of other videos on deploying with these methods if you do not understand from these videos.

Comment: thanks for the videos, but it means I have to host the front end separately and backend separately, is it right?

Comment: @ArjadGohar Yes this is right but this is usually the case however there is one site where you can host all in one place I forgot its name but I will get back to you when i find it

Comment: I found it's name Zeet I haven't used it my self but i have seen others use it

Comment: thank you i will check that, i have one more question if you can help ,

Comment: i have uploaded my front end successfully on bluehost cpannel, and it is running fine, now I have also uploaded backend on node js on capnnel nad dit shows the following( screenshot https://ibb.co/2820Tpb) ,

can you tell me it node js is hosted successfully or not

Comment: @ArjadGohar Try setting up an app.get() to just show a simple hello world or something and you can try accessing the site. If you can access it then it is successful i guess